# PSQLException: ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type xml

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

**JPQL:**

```
select distinct ref 
FROM Data d 
  inner join d.reference ref 
WHERE d.role = 'admin'  
ORDER BY ref.id
```

This JPA query fails with following error:

> PSQLException: ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type
>   xml

Versions: PostgreSQL 9.3 and JDK 1.7

The Data entity contains an xml type field. ref in query refers Data type object, ie Data entity itself refers an object of type Data.
It will work if we use PK field for distinct but need to return unique object not just id. We are using JPA query language not native query. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that `ref` is of type `xml`; if not, show your table definitions.

You'll probably have to cast `ref` to type `text`, since equality is not defined for `xml`, and how shall you handle `DISTINCT` without a notion of what equality is?

Alternatively, you could use a different data type or use `CREATE OPERATOR` to define an equality operator on `xml`. But when are two XML documents equal?

Comment: I'd guess that he is using JPQL and not SQL. JPQL does not need an "ON" clause, he is joining across relations.

Comment: Yes, I have given JPQL query. ref is of type Data ie, Data entity itself has reference to another Data entity. I am fetching full Data object using JPA (Hibernate). That's why cast to text or DISTINCT on PK field not applicable in this case.

Comment: I see. Well, if you use an ORM that is so limited than you cannot specify a type cast, you might either use a different data type or define an equality operator for `xml`.